# C# Attribute hell - one class shared between mobile and server on two different SQL platforms

Tags: c#, xamarin, custom-attributes, ormlite-servicestack, sqlite.net

We share a single poco's with

- ServiceStack WebServices
- ServiceStack Orm with MySQL
- Xamarin mobile client that uses Sqlite.net.

Problem is the shared classes have become a mess.

```
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
#if __MOBILE__
        [Indexed]
#else
        [Index]
#endif
        public string UserAccountId { get; set; }
#if __MOBILE__
        [Indexed]
#else
        [Index]
#endif
```

And if it's not bad enough already, i need to

- Constrain the length of each field in the database....
- Save these objects in MongoDb.  Fortunately, they have an AutoMapper
  class that does this at runtime.

Not sure what to do.  My Failed ideas include:

- Try to use:  [Conditional("DEBUG")].  But it does nothing for this
- It appears that sqlite.net uses its own attribute

  [AttributeUsage (AttributeTargets.Property)]
      public class IndexedAttribute : Attribute

  So it won't find the Mysql [Index] attribute
- Could try to include two attributes on each property

  [Indexed]
  [Index]
  public string UserAccountId { get; set; }
- I tried to turn it into a two one line'ers but c# VS complains

> ```
> #if __MOBILE__ [Indexed]  #endif 
> #if __MOBILE__ [Index]    #endif
> ```

In the end, the only approach that ** APPEARS ** will work is to just keep the interface as the single definition of the class and have many concrete classes that get decorated differently.

Any Ideas??

Comment: It's not a POCO if you have all those attributes on there. Probably a strong point in favor of using a fluent model builder rather than attributes.

Comment: Your right, its not a poco. Q: I assume i would need to build the ModelBuilder class myself.  Is there some general purpose framework that i could use as an overlay? I assume the one in EntityFramework is not going to work.

Comment: I am not familiar with ServiceStack.OrmLite so unfortunately I don't know what your options are there.

Comment: Apparently we can keep both defined.  So this syntax is valid         

[Indexed,Index]
public string UserAccountId

Answer (score 4):

If you were to architect your code as per Uncle Bob's Clean Architecture, you wouldn't attempt to have a single representation to be used for many different purposes, as it causes your dependencies to point outwards from high-level policy towards outer circles.

[image: Clean Architecture]

Source: https://8thlight.com/blog/uncle-bob/2012/08/13/the-clean-architecture.html

Effectively, you could put an *Entity* in the centre circle, along with enterprise business rules, but the DTO you use to store/retrieve data for a particular database should be way out in your "frameworks and drivers" circle.

All of those database-specific attributes belong on DTOs in the blue circle, not on the entities in the centre.

Comment: So, basically my last choice, keep and interface and multiple concrete classes for each implementation.  Im going to provide a sample below.

Answer (score 0):

So, Uncle Bob and Fenton's suggestion is basically my last choice. Make changes to the Interface.

I will user Re-sharper to updates all classes the classes..

This should work.

```
namespace Evaluation.Entitys
{
    public interface IUserEntity
    {
        string UserAccountId { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserEntity : IUserEntity
    {
        public string UserAccountId { get; set; }

        public UserEntity()
        {

        }
    }

    public class UserEntityTransport : IUserEntity
    {
        public string UserAccountId { get; set; }

        public UserEntityTransport(IUserEntity e)
        {
            UserAccountId = e.UserAccountId;
        }
    }
}
#if __MOBILE__

namespace Evaluation.Moible 
{


    using SQLite;
    using SQLite.Net;
    public class UserEntityMobileDB : IUserEntity
    {
        [Index]
        public string UserAccountId { get; set; }
        public UserEntityMobileDB(IUserEntity e)
        {
            UserAccountId = e.UserAccountId;
        }
    }
}
#endif

#if __WIN32__
namespace Evaluation.Server
{
    using Evaluation.Entitys;
    using ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;
    using SQLite;

    public class UserEntityServerDB : IUserEntity
    {
        [Indexed]
        public string UserAccountId { get; set; }

        public UserEntityServerDB(IUserEntity e)
        {
            UserAccountId = e.UserAccountId;

        }
    }
}
#endif
```

This should work.

Drawbacks

1. Need to maintain multiple 4x copy constructors, at the controller
   level.
2. One class is now 4 classes.

Answer (score 0):

Mason's suggestion would be to create a fluent like Model Builder.  Since this does not currently exist ??? in ServiceStack.OrmLine and SqlLite.net I assume i would have to build it.

I found this code sample from entity framework.

```
modelBuilder 
    .Entity<Person>() 
    .Property(t => t.Name) 
    .HasColumnAnnotation( 
        "Index",  
        new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Name") { IsUnique = true }));
```

My psudocode version would look like:

```
modelBuilder 
    .Entity<UserEntity>() 
    .Property(t => t.UserAccountId) 
    .AddColumnIndex(new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_Name") {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this syntax is valid and should also work.

```
using SQLite;
using ORMLite = ServiceStack.DataAnnotations;

[ORMLite.PrimaryKey, ORMLite.AutoIncrement]
[SQLite.PrimaryKey, SQLite.AutoIncrement]
public int Id { get; set; }

[Indexed,Index]
public string UserAccountId { get; set; }
```